# Ayuda con ejercicio en PHP utilizando $_POST

Tags: php, post

Ayuda con este ejercicio, no logro saber que está mal.
El formulario que nos llega viaja por POST tiene un

```
<input type="text" name="edad">
```

El objetivo es completar la función validar edad que se fije si el valor enviado es un número entero y si es mayor (o igual) a 18 retornando un booleano
Podrías utilizar la función is_integer

```
             function validarEdad() {
                               if(is_integer($_POST["edad"] >= 18)) {
                               return true;
                               }
                              else {
                               return false;
                                }
                                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La funcion `is_integer()` sirve para validar si una variable contiene un entero o no.  Estas tratando de chequear las dos condiciones al mismo tiempo.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
function validarEdad() {
       if(is_integer($_POST["edad"]) && $_POST["edad"] >= 18) {
            return true;
       } else {
            return false;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extendiendo la respuesta de alanfcm, puedes simplificar tu función de esta manera:

```
function validarEdad() {
    return is_integer($_POST["edad"]) && $_POST["edad"] >= 18;
}
```

Genera el mismo resultado a que si explícitamente agregaras el `if...else` y los `return true|false`.

Comment: por favor lee [answer], edita y explica tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

¿Quieres validar si es un número entero por alguna razón en especial? Te lo digo porque otra cosa que puedes hacer es insertar el dato como type number en el formulario y al llegar al controlador, comprobar directamente si es mayor que 18.

```
<input type="number" name="edad">

function validarEdad() {
       if($_POST["edad"] >= 18) {
            return true;
       } else {
            return false;
       }
```